# how to connect PHP application with ERP system?

Tags: php, mysql, erp

I have created PHP application for company. and company also have ERP. I want to connect my application with ERP. so that employee can login by company's website which is in PHP and can access functionality of ERP. How do I proceed ? Please guide. and also provide some links for development

Comment: There is not really an answer for that. It all depends on the degree on integration, what ERP system it is, how your infrastructure is set up, etc.

Comment: There is an infinite (or close to it) number of possible answers.

Comment: can we connect mysql database with erp's database ?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka will you please give me one answer ?

Comment: ERP is broader term , you need to narrow down to specific database is being used for ERP

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan so is there any way to connect with PHP or mysql ? any suggestion for database ?

Comment: or else is there any way that we can connect erp's database with my php application?

Comment: You want one answer so here you go: Assuming that there is no knowledge about that erp, no knowledge about database (you did not specify any of these) - no you cant. And I hope that you will get the point about this answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have very broad question and just considering that you need to get information from `ERP` system on your PHP portal. and i also considering you are the administrator of `ERP` as well.

`ERP` (Enterprise Resource Planning) is being provided by different vendors and Major includes `Epicor`,`Infor`,`Oracle` and `SAP`. All vendors are using Different databases. So for integration you must need to know what database is being used. For Such applications mostly used databases are `SQL` and `Oracle` .

After you get the type of database , next step is to know the schema or specific `table` to get the information. Now Suppose you are getting information from oracle. you can use below connection string.

```
$dbc = new PDO('oci:dbname=Serveraddress/orcl;charset=CL8MSWIN1251', 'username', 'password');
```

you can also use the web services like `SOAP` or `REST` which ever supported by your ERP to fetch information.

For Specially `SAP` below link can help you
[Intgration of PHP & SAP](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/a5d5b6f6-0301-0010-4fae-f3b91bcfd642?overridelayout=true)

Comment: Thanks for information this will defiantly help me a lot